# Quota exceeded error in Google Cloud Function provided by Cloudflare

Tags: google-bigquery

We used the Google Cloud Function provided by Cloudflare to import data from Google Cloud Storage in to Google BigQuery (refer to: https://developers.cloudflare.com/logs/analytics-integrations/google-cloud/). The cloud function was running into an error saying:
"Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table"

I queried the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT table and found the errorresult.location is 'load_job_per_table.long'. The jobid is '26bb1792-1ca4-42c6-b61f-54abca74a2ee'.

Looked at the Quotas page for BigQuery API service but non of the quotas status showed exceeded. Some are blank though.

Could anyone help me with which Google Cloud Quota or limit it exceeded? If so, how to increase the quota? The cloudflare function is used by another google account and it works well without any error.

Thanks,
Jinglei

Comment: See "Requesting an increase in quota"
https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But how to identify which quota is exceeded? The quota page does not show any warnings. Some other post saying it is the Load Data limit - Load jobs per table per day — 1,500 (including failures), but how to increase it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for the specific quota error in Cloud Logging where there are log entries.
I had a similar issues with BigQuery Data Transfer quota being reached. Please see my example Cloud Logging filter:

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
severity=ERROR
timestamp>="2021-01-14T00:00:00-08:00"
textPayload:"429 Quota"
```

Change the timestamp according and maybe remove the textPayload filter.
You can also just click in the interface for severe errors and search in the UI.

Here is another example:

```
severity=ERROR
timestamp>="2021-01-16T00:00:00-08:00"
NOT protoPayload.status.message:"Already Exists: Dataset ga360-bigquery-azuredatalake"
NOT protoPayload.status.message:"Syntax error"
NOT protoPayload.status.message:"Not found"
NOT protoPayload.status.message:"Table name"
NOT textPayload:"project_transfer_config_path"
NOT protoPayload.methodName : "InsertDataset"
textPayload:"429 Quota"
```

Comment: Also, you should be able to increase the quota on the Quotas page under the specific quota that is being passed. Google support and maybe Google Billing support could help.

Answer (score 0):

Identify quota will be done by What different action you are performing through your function, it could be any .. Insert, Update, Volume, External IP and so on. Then try to analysis frequency or metric values and try to evaluate with Google defined quotas it will give you an indicator which quota is getting exceeded.
You can refer following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-kbSmdRzAQ) over same.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare says they have a fix coming for the quota issue:  https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-gcp/issues/72

Comment: GCP support confirmed they do not allow increase of the 1500 loads/table/day quota: "Upon further investigation, the product team does not increase this quota. As a workaround you can combine load jobs to reduce the number of them or use Streaming Inserts.If the requirement is to get real-time up-to date data in your tables you should use the streaming api [1] instead of load jobs."